# JAVA - custom error response for invalid data

Tags: java, json, rest

I wrote a `post` controller to handle a date from `JSON` request.

Right now, for invalid dates, it returns a general 500 error without description.

(i.e "statusDate": "2017-13-27")

How can I return a custom error message instead of a general one?

(i.e "Invalid date in 'statusDate' ")

This is the code:

```
  public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        format.setLenient(false);
        String dateAsString = jp.getText();

        if (dateAsString.isEmpty())
            return null;

        try {
            Date date = format.parse(dateAsString);
            if (dateAsString.split("-")[0].length() != 4)
                throw new RuntimeException();
            return date;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);  //Here is the exception I want to change
        }
    }
```

Comment: you mean changing the exception text? `throw new RuntimeException("bananas", e);` ?

Comment: Kind of. The problem is that even if I change the text it returns a general exception (500).

Comment: You should start by throwing a JsonProcessingException. Then the parser, and then the framework, will know that it's a JSON problem, and will return the appropriate status code.

Comment: Custom errors should be handled by a common handler. There you can tweak the serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a message when creating the [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html#RuntimeException(java.lang.String)):

```
try {
    Date date = format.parse(dateAsString);
    if (dateAsString.split("-")[0].length() != 4)
        throw new RuntimeException("Another custom message");
    return date;
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Your custom message", e);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _pass a **method**_?

Comment: Typo. Should have been _message_. Will fix it.